# How can I use GRPC request?

Tags: java, android, routes, google-api, grpc-java

Sorry newbie question, I'm a still learning and this is my first time learning about GRPC and been trying to implement Routing API to my app. My question is how can I implement or use GRPC so that I can use the routing API or is there any way to use Routing API without GRPC.

I saw this code in the Routing API documentation on google, thought that I need to configure GRPC first before fully utilizing this.

```
package com.example;

import com.google.maps.routing.v2.*;
import com.google.type.LatLng;
import io.grpc.CallOptions;
import io.grpc.Channel;
import io.grpc.ClientCall;
import io.grpc.ClientInterceptor;
import io.grpc.ClientInterceptors;
import io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall;
import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.MethodDescriptor;
import io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException;
import io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RoutesClient {
   // For more detail on inserting API keys, see:
   // https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys#java
   // For more detail on system parameters (such as FieldMask), see:
   // https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters
   private static final class RoutesInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
       private final String apiKey;
       private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RoutesInterceptor.class.getName());
       private static Metadata.Key API_KEY_HEADER = Metadata.Key.of("x-goog-api-key",
               Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
       private static Metadata.Key FIELD_MASK_HEADER = Metadata.Key.of("x-goog-fieldmask",
               Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

       public RoutesInterceptor(String apiKey) {
           this.apiKey = apiKey;
       }

       @Override
       public  ClientCall interceptCall(MethodDescriptor method,
               CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
           logger.info("Intercepted " + method.getFullMethodName());
           ClientCall call = next.newCall(method, callOptions);
           call = new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall(call) {
               @Override
               public void start(Listener responseListener, Metadata headers) {
                   headers.put(API_KEY_HEADER, apiKey);
                   // Note that setting the field mask to * is OK for testing, but discouraged in
                   // production.
                   // For example, for ComputeRoutes, set the field mask to
                   // "routes.distanceMeters,routes.duration,routes.polyline.encodedPolyline"
                   // in order to get the route distances, durations, and encoded polylines.
                   headers.put(FIELD_MASK_HEADER, "*");
                   super.start(responseListener, headers);
               }
           };
           return call;
       }
   }

   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RoutesClient.class.getName());
   private final RoutesGrpc.RoutesBlockingStub blockingStub;

   public RoutesClient(Channel channel) {
       blockingStub = RoutesGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
   }

   public static Waypoint createWaypointForLatLng(double lat, double lng) {
       return Waypoint.newBuilder()
               .setLocation(Location.newBuilder().setLatLng(LatLng.newBuilder().setLatitude(lat).setLongitude(lng)))
               .build();
   }

   public void computeRoutes() {
       ComputeRoutesRequest request = ComputeRoutesRequest.newBuilder()
               .setOrigin(createWaypointForLatLng(37.420761, -122.081356))
               .setDestination(createWaypointForLatLng(37.420999, -122.086894)).setTravelMode(RouteTravelMode.DRIVE)
               .setRoutingPreference(RoutingPreference.TRAFFIC_AWARE).setComputeAlternativeRoutes(true)
               .setRouteModifiers(
                       RouteModifiers.newBuilder().setAvoidTolls(false).setAvoidHighways(true).setAvoidFerries(true))
               .setPolylineQuality(PolylineQuality.OVERVIEW).build();
       ComputeRoutesResponse response;
       try {
           logger.info("About to send request: " + request.toString());
           response = blockingStub.withDeadlineAfter(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).computeRoutes(request);
       } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
           logger.log(Level.WARNING, "RPC failed: {0}", e.getStatus());
           return;
       }
       logger.info("Response: " + response.toString());
   }

   public void computeRouteMatrix() {
       ComputeRouteMatrixRequest request = ComputeRouteMatrixRequest.newBuilder()
               .addOrigins(RouteMatrixOrigin.newBuilder().setWaypoint(createWaypointForLatLng(37.420761, -122.081356))
                       .setRouteModifiers(RouteModifiers.newBuilder().setAvoidTolls(false).setAvoidHighways(true)
                               .setAvoidFerries(true)))
               .addOrigins(RouteMatrixOrigin.newBuilder().setWaypoint(createWaypointForLatLng(37.403184, -122.097371)))
               .addDestinations(RouteMatrixDestination.newBuilder()
                       .setWaypoint(createWaypointForLatLng(37.420999, -122.086894)))
               .addDestinations(RouteMatrixDestination.newBuilder()
                       .setWaypoint(createWaypointForLatLng(37.383047, -122.044651)))
               .setTravelMode(RouteTravelMode.DRIVE).setRoutingPreference(RoutingPreference.TRAFFIC_AWARE).build();
       Iterator elements;
       try {
           logger.info("About to send request: " + request.toString());
           elements = blockingStub.withDeadlineAfter(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).computeRouteMatrix(request);
       } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
           logger.log(Level.WARNING, "RPC failed: {0}", e.getStatus());
           return;
       }

       while (elements.hasNext()) {
           logger.info("Element response: " + elements.next().toString());
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       String apiKey = System.getenv("INSERT_API_KEY_HERE");

       // The standard TLS port is 443
       Channel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("routes.googleapis.com", 443).build();
       channel = ClientInterceptors.intercept(channel, new RoutesInterceptor(apiKey));

       RoutesClient client = new RoutesClient(channel);
       client.computeRoutes();
       client.computeRouteMatrix();
   }
}
``
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are wanting to achieve. Can you explain more about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, I wanted to use the Routing API for the project that I am currently doing, in the documentation GRPC request can be use to call the routes that I need but after trying the code above there seem to be a lot of error it might be because I did not configure GRPC properly? or some codes are missing. I have no idea what could be the problem or what are things that I should do first before using routing API.